# ¿Algoritmo en C++ para encontrar mayor valor impar?

Tags: c++

Buenas, estoy resolviendo un ejercicio de la facu y es un programa que genera n matrices con valores pseudoaleatorio. 
Estoy en esta funcion:

> 2.Función " void imparmayor( ...)": detecta en el arreglo"MInicio[ ][ ]" el mayor valor impar y su posición: fila y columna" y lo guarda en un arreglo
>     "mayorimpar[ n][3 ]".

Logro generar n matrices de 10x10 nros aleatorios, pero no logro hacer un algoritmo que encuentre el mayor valor impar de cada una, puedo encontrar por separado el mayor, y por otra parte los impares pero no juntos.

Comment: solo guardalos en un array

Comment: Con un poco del código que has hecho seria mas facil ayudarte. en todo caso lo que debes hacer son dos ciclos for iterados con una variable que se actualice si la condicion (if) de ser impar y ser mayor que el antiguo impar mayor se cumple ademas dos variables mas x e y que te guarden los valores de los dos ciclos for dichos previamente

Comment: ¿ Que código tienes hasta ahora ? La parte mínima necesaria, junto a unos datos de ejemplo: esperados y obtenidos. Con código **siempre** es mas fácil responder :-)

Comment: ahora les muestro, lo deje en stand by y pase a otra cosa:

http://textuploader.com/dm2wl

Comment: Edita la pregunta y añade ahí el texto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al principio creas una variable para suponer que es el mayor

```
int mayor = Miinicio[0][0];
```

Después recorres la matriz con ayuda de dos ciclos `for`, del 0 hasta el 10.
Y realizas esta validacion

```
if((Miinicio[i][j] % 2) == 0)
  if (Miinicio[i][j] > mayor)
    mayor = Miinicio[i][j];
```

Al final tendrás el valor mayor par.
Para obtener el mayor impar solo cambias el == por !=

Comment: muchas gracias Jose! habia llegado a una conclusion similar , ahora solo tengo que pasarle la matriz por referencia y listo ese modulo.